# Equality operator that supports comparing two references to objects?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, operator-overloading

This is pre-existing code which works fine.

```
bool operator==(CMyClass X) {return m_Data==X.m_Data;}

if(a == b){...} //a and b are both CMyClass objects
```

But now I have code:

```
if(x.get() == y.get()){...} // get() returns CMyClass&
```

I already changed it to take a const reference

```
bool operator==(const CMyClass &X) {return m_Data==X.m_Data;}
```

And I still get the compile error:

> error C2678: binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand
>   operand of type 'const CMyClass' (or there is no acceptable
>   conversion)

Do I need a simple amendment to my existing operator, or to add a new 2-arg version?
Should equality operators not take const ref parameters as best practice anyway?

Comment: make operator== a "const" operator

Comment: change: `bool operator==(const CMyClass &X) {return m_Data==X.m_Data;}` to `bool operator==(const CMyClass &X) const {return m_Data==X.m_Data;}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An equality operator should take its parameter by const reference (since it won't be making any changes to the value), and also be a const function (if it is a class member).

So your declaration should be

```
bool operator==(const CMyClass &X) const {return m_Data==X.m_Data;}
```

Since your `get` function returns a `const CMyClass &`, your original equality comparison is uncallable since it is not a `const` function and can't be called on a const object.